# sklearn custom transformer fitting problems

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have created a custom transformer based on the OneHotEncoder from SKLearn. However, after having called fit, transform tells me that the OneHotEncoder is not fitted yet and I have no idea, why. The simplified version ( I also derive from another class which I dropped here, as it is not necessary ) below. I debugged and the fit method is called correctly. The error I get:

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.


class CustomOneHotEncoder(OneHotEncoder):
"""
OneHot Encoding
----------
"""

# todo: max_num_categories als parameter
def __init__(self, categories='auto', drop=None, sparse=True, dtype=np.int, handle_unknown='error'):
    OneHotEncoder.__init__(self, categories=categories, drop=drop, sparse=sparse, dtype=dtype, handle_unknown=handle_unknown)

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    OneHotEncoder.fit(self, X, y=y)
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    """
    :type X: DataFrame
    """
    try:
        ret = OneHotEncoder().transform(X).toarray()  # Here I get the error
        return ret
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("Internal Error")
```

Comment: where are fitting ont X, y?

Comment: It is in the fit method, which is called before transform is called. The OneHotEncoder fitted herein is the super() one, I just cannot call super as I in derive from another class not shown here.

Comment: it's better attach full code that we can debug

Comment: The code as shown above can be debugged, just needs an import 'from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `OneHotEncoder.xyz` you're referring either to the class or a fresh instance of the class, so none of the `__init__`, `fit`, or `transform` methods actually see each other's updates.  You need to use `super` (and perhaps you can expand your example to show a version of that intermediate class, so we can help figure out how to use `super` there?), or else have your class contain an attribute that is a `OneHotEncoder` instead of inheriting.

Comment: Hi Ben, I figured that out, also. However, there are other pitfalls like that the parameters of super are anti intuitiv (i.e. the first parameter does not reference the class you want but actually skips it). I got it working meanwhile using the super call.